# returning oracle cursor results to json python

Tags: python, json, oracle

I am working with python oracle connection. But i have a issue returning date with the cursor result as json.

below is the json result of the cursor, the issue is format of create_dttm. When creating a dataframe from this it is not changing the format. Any suggestion

```
result = cursur.execute("**my query**")
data = list(result)
final = json.dumps(data)
print(final)
[{"create_dttm": {"$date": 1677264505842}, "update_dttm": {"$date": 1677264505842}, "wo_id": "ABC-63953"},{"create_dttm": {"$date": 1677264505843}, "update_dttm": {"$date": 1677264505843}, "wo_id": "ABC-63954"}]
```

I want the data to be like below when creating a dataframe

```
create_dttm   update_dttm   wo_id
2021-5-09     2021-5-09    ABC-63953
2021-5-09     2021-5-09    ABC-63953
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Define the list of JSON objects
json_list = [{"create_dttm": {"$date": 1677264505842}, "update_dttm": {"$date": 1677264505842}, "wo_id": "ABC-63953"},
             {"create_dttm": {"$date": 1677264505843}, "update_dttm": {"$date": 1677264505843}, "wo_id": "ABC-63954"}]


dfItem = pd.DataFrame.from_records(json_list)
print(dfItem)

# to get only the timestamp
dfItem['create_dttm'] = dfItem['create_dttm'].map(lambda x: x['$date'])

dfItem['update_dttm'] = dfItem['update_dttm'].map(lambda x: x['$date'])

# converting the milliseconds to date time
dfItem['create_dttm'] = pd.to_datetime(dfItem['create_dttm'], unit='ms')
dfItem['update_dttm'] = pd.to_datetime(dfItem['update_dttm'], unit='ms')

# keeping only the date
dfItem['create_dttm'] =dfItem['create_dttm'].dt.date
dfItem['update_dttm'] =dfItem['update_dttm'].dt.date

print(dfItem)
```

Output:
[image]

Also see if there's a way you can directly convert the milliseconds to date time format and then extract only the date from it.

Answer (score 0):

I created below function to help solve my question, used some parts from previous answer as well. But this works effeciently

```
date_columns = ['create_dttm','update_dttm']
def clean_dateset(df):
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df)
    for i in df.columns:
        if i in date_columns:
            df[i] = df[i].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.get('$date'), unit='ms', errors = 'coerce').date())
    return df

my_fina_dataset = clean_dateset(df)
```